# make section of text in text area static?

Tags: html, textarea

Is there a way to make only a portion of text in a text area static or read-only without disabling the entire text area?

Basically, I want a person to be able to update a status using a textarea, and the static text would have their name and the verb is at the begining, like:

Eric is: "Riding a bike"

Is this possible?

```
Basic text area <input="textarea" blah="" blah"">
```

Comment: I would suggest creating a div box with a gray border to look like a textarea. put a piece of text at the upper left with the actual textarea bumping up against it. Then style the textarea so there's no border.

Comment: Not without using javascript to fake the effect. You'd have to handle keyboard events, mouse events and be able to identify your caret position within the textarea - all in a cross-browser friendly way. I'd run to the hills with my hands in the air!.... Or use something that makes more sense - Show the "Eric is:" inside a label, have the "Riding a bike" inside a text input. The javascript needed to populate the label with that text is minuscule compared to that required to do it all with a textarea. I.e  <label>Eric is: < textarea type='textarea' blah="\" blah\"" value='Riding a bike'></label>

Comment: @enhzflep, make that an answer.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - done and done. :)

Comment: Yes you can do easily if you want to put your readonly text at beginning. using `onkeydown and onenter` events of textbox. if your curs cursor is say within first 10 characters disable any keydown until your cursor position is greater than 10. Hope you get little idea

Answer (score 0):

Further to the wishes of Jukka,

Not without using javascript to fake the effect. You'd have to handle keyboard events, mouse events and be able to identify your caret position within the textarea - all in a cross-browser friendly way. I'd run to the hills with my hands in the air!....

Or use something that makes more sense -

Show the "Eric is:" inside a label, have the "Riding a bike" inside a text input. The javascript needed to populate the label with that text is minuscule compared to that required to do it all with a textarea. 
The markup could be as simple as:

```
<label>Eric is: <input type='textarea' blah="\" blah\"" value='Riding a bike'></label>
```